# Php MySQL update table textarea html

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

I have a table where ResultHRM column contains a textarea where the user can write comments. I would like to know, when I click on submit button how can update the correct line with the textarea content into my MySQL table NContrib ?
I read that textarea cannot have a value attribute.

My table NContrib has the following structure:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| IdVariantNContrib | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ID                | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Reference         | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ResultHRM         | varchar(60)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In my php page, I display this table like that:

```
    <form method='POST' action='SaveValidation.php'>
    <?php
    require_once 'config.php'; //database connection
    $sql='SELECT ID, Reference, ResultHRM FROM NContrib';
    $PerformSql=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    ?>
<table style="width:100%" border='1px' CELLSPACING='0' cellpadding='2'>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;ID&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;Reference&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;ResultsHRM&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
<?php
while($rowNcontrib =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformSql)) {
  echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;".$rowNcontrib["ID"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowNcontrib["Reference"]."&nbsp;</td><td><textarea name='ResultHRM[]' id='ResultHRM[]' cols='30' rows='1'></textarea></td></tr>";
 }
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="sendEcht" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: textarea has a name In php you can get the $_POST['your_text_area_name'] value....

Comment: and when you want to display your content just put it inside <textarea>"you content here"</textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) use `$rowNcontrib['ResultHRM']` in beetween `<textarea></textarea>` to show `value`

2) Also use have use  `name='ResultHRM[]'` this will give you a `array` of `textarea` values which you have updated but you will not get track of which value belongs to which `ID`. so `name='ResultHRM[$id]'`. here `id` should be the id of `row`

So your code should be

like

```
 while($rowNcontrib =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformSql)) {
        $id = $rowNcontrib["ID"];
      echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;".$rowNcontrib["ID"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowNcontrib["Reference"]."&nbsp;</td><td><textarea name='ResultHRM[$id]' id='ResultHRM[]' cols='30' rows='1'>".$rowNcontrib['ResultHRM ']."</textarea></td></tr>";
     }
```

now in page `SaveValidation.php` check for this

```
 if(isset($_POST['sendEcht'])){
 echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die;}
```

this will show you something like this

```
Array
(
    [ResultHRM] => Array
        (
            [3] => hello its test
            [11] => test string
            [10] => 

        )

    [sendEcht] => Submit
)

// here 3,11, 10 are my id's of table in your case it will be the id's of your table then you can easily update your table `ResultHRM` field
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I just have one question about the ID. When I submitted my form, I can easily get the textarea content by doing: `$textarea=$_POST['ResultHRM'];`, but for the id, how can I do ? In my mind, I was doing like that: `foreach ($textarea as $value)
{ $sql='UPDATE TABLE SET ResultHRM='.$textarea.' where id=??'}`

Comment: I think I get it, I did like that to get my id: `$textarea=$_POST['ResultHRM']; foreach(array_values($textarea) as $i => $value)
{
$j=$i+1;
echo 'UPDATE TABLE SET ResultHRM="'.$value.'" where ID='.$j.'<br/> ';
}`

Answer (score 0):

There are certain points that I would like to mention here:

1. If `ResultHRM` field is going to hold the values from textarea in form, I would suggest that you change the datatype. Currently, its `varchar(60)`. I suggest, it should be `text`.
2. After fetching the data from the database, you are displaying it in the table structure. I would suggest, you add textarea and fill it with existing value. Let's assume you named textarea `ResultHRM_ta`
3. Once you will follow point#2, and submit the form, you can have textarea value in `$_POST['ResultHRM_ta']` on `SaveValidation.php`.
4. Save the value in database.

Please note, I have mentioned the very basic outline for the process you need to follow. You will have to take care of security measures and coding standards on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Tow solve this you can call a AJAX request with the code and pass id for each in the javascript method.

and in html code in the you can call method in each table row as follows:

```
<table style="width:100%" border='1px' CELLSPACING='0' cellpadding='2'>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;ID&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;Reference&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;ResultsHRM&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
<?php
while($rowNcontrib =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformSql)) {
  echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;".$rowNcontrib["ID"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowNcontrib["Reference"]."&nbsp;</td><td><textarea name='ResultHRM' id='ResultHRM' cols='30' rows='1'></textarea></td><td><button type='button' onclick='update(".$rowNcontrib["ID"].")'">Update</button>;
 }
?>
</table>
```